# is angular's compile function async?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, compilation

I have a service in which I call `$compile` to compile my template. Function in JS are getting executed one after another. However, in order get my final HTML I have to put `html()` in timeout callback. Otherwise, I get my template with `{{ placeholders }}` only. The questions is why I need to use timeout here? Here is my code:

```
var newScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
angular.extend(newScope, data);
var compiled = $compile(template);
var linked = compiled(newScope);

$timeout(function () {
  def.resolve(linked.html());
});
```

Comment: Is this wrapped in a bound HTML event?  Like a `click`?  You may need a `$scope.$apply()`.  `$timeout` does an `$apply` as a side effect underneath so this could be the reason it works.

Comment: This method is called $on angular event. But my question is why do I need to wrap `linked.HTML()` in $timeout or call $apply? Actually, it is not because of $apply. I can also set vanilla `setTimeout` with 0 delay and resolve promise with compiled template. It seems that it has something to do with JS internal function call queue. I thought that in js functions execute one after another. Regardless how much time does it takes to execute a function. But this case shows that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

No, $compile is not asynchronous. Calling $timeout is necessary because of the nature of the browser and the relationship between JavaScript and the DOM. The $timeout allows the DOM to be updated so that your call to .html() actually *has* html to return.

Your example is correctly using $compile and $timeout.

**A couple of notes:**

$timeout already returns a promise which is resolved with the return value of the passed function, so you could simply do this:

```
return $timeout(function(){
    return linked.html();
});
```

As you have it, the outermost (root) element of your template gets thrown away because .html() returns the innerHTML of that element. If you need to preserve that root element you can wrap it in a div first like so:

```
return $timeout(function(){
    return angular.element('<div/>').append(linked).html();
});
```

Complete example:

```
var $scope = angular.extend($rootScope.$new(true), data);
var template = angular.element($templateCache.get(templateName));

$compile(template)($scope);

return $timeout(function(){
    return angular.element('<div/>').append(template).html();
});
```